# my js works in another browser but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click on button ajax must load more contents and to throw the user in top of the new load contents.Function worked perfectly in mozilla and IE but not in Chrome i don't know where is the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
if ($showMoreOffersButton) { ?>
        <div class="text-center box" id="show-more-tourism-offers-btn-holder">
            <a class="site-button blue" onclick="showMoreTourismOffers(<?php echo $offset; ?>)"
               onclick="ga('send', 'event', '<?= isset($parent_component) ? $parent_component : 'Unknown' ?>', 'Show More Offers' );">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning" id="travel-arrow-spinner"
                      style="display: none"></span>
                ОЩЕ ОФЕРТИ
            </a>
        </div>
    <? }



function showMoreTourismOffers(begin_offset) {
if (!btn_lock) {
    //check if user already visited this page and saw more than 16 boxes
    if (offset < begin_offset) {
        offset = begin_offset;
    }
    var mobileFlag;
    if(isMobile == 1){
        mobileFlag = true;
    }else{
        mobileFlag = false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'pochivki/show_more_offers/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            filter: ajaxDealFilter(true, mobileFlag),
            country_index: countryIndex,
            region_index: regionIndex,
            city_index: cityIndex,
            offset: offset,
            current_url: window.location.href
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#tourism-deals-holder').append(data.deals);
            if (data.hideButton) {
                $('#show-more-tourism-offers-btn-holder').remove();
            }
             offset += 48;
            $('#travel-arrow-spinner').hide();
        },
        error: function () {
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            btn_lock = !btn_lock; // becomes true
            $('#travel-arrow-spinner').show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            btn_lock = !btn_lock; // becomes false again
            $('.images-rotation').imagesRotation()
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}   }
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome and go to the Console tab

Comment: no nothing in the console

Answer (score -1):

solving this problem  i hope this help of anyone who have the same problem

```
function showMoreTourismOffers(begin_offset) {
if (!btn_lock) {
    //check if user already visited this page and saw more than 16 boxes
    if (offset < begin_offset) {
        offset = begin_offset;
    }
    var mobileFlag;
    if(isMobile == 1){
        mobileFlag = true;
    }else{
        mobileFlag = false;
    }

    var buttonPosition = $('#show-more-tourism-offers-btn-holder').position();
    var buttonPositionTop = buttonPosition.top;

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'pochivki/show_more_offers/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            filter: ajaxDealFilter(true, mobileFlag),
            country_index: countryIndex,
            region_index: regionIndex,
            city_index: cityIndex,
            offset: offset,
            current_url: window.location.href
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#tourism-deals-holder').append(data.deals);
            $('body').scrollTop(buttonPositionTop);
            if (data.hideButton) {
                $('#show-more-tourism-offers-btn-holder').remove();
            }
             offset += 48;
            $('#travel-arrow-spinner').hide();
        },
        error: function () {

        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            btn_lock = !btn_lock; // becomes true
            $('#travel-arrow-spinner').show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            btn_lock = !btn_lock; // becomes false again
            $('.images-rotation').imagesRotation()
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

}